# Mapped types break when mapping to an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Given a type that describes my `Dependencies` and `Container` I want to register a provider function for each dependency.

The code below has 2 implementations of the "registry"

1. `DependencyProviders` - a map between the dependency name and its provider
2. `DependencyRegistry` - a map between the dependency name and an object that holds its provider

Can you please help me understand why the second option throws a TS error?

```js
interface Dependencies {
  a: string
  b: number
  c: boolean
}

type DependencyProviders = {
  [DepName in keyof Dependencies]: () => Dependencies[DepName]
}

type DependencyRegistry = {
  [DepName in keyof Dependencies]: {
    provider: () => Dependencies[DepName]
  }
}

class Container {
  private readonly providers: Partial<DependencyProviders> = {}
  private readonly registry: Partial<DependencyRegistry> = {}

  register<DepName extends keyof Dependencies>(
    name: DepName,
    provider: DependencyProviders[DepName]
  ) {
    this.providers[name] = provider
    this.registry[name] = { provider }
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  }
}
```

The line `this.registry[name] = { provider }` throws the following error:

```
Type '{ provider: DependencyProviders[DepName]; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<DependencyRegistry>[DepName]'.
  Type '{ provider: DependencyProviders[DepName]; }' is not assignable to type '{ provider: () => string; } & { provider: () => number; } & { provider: () => boolean; }'.
    Type '{ provider: DependencyProviders[DepName]; }' is not assignable to type '{ provider: () => string; }'.
      Types of property 'provider' are incompatible.
        Type 'DependencyProviders[DepName]' is not assignable to type '() => string'.
          Type '(() => string) | (() => number) | (() => boolean)' is not assignable to type '() => string'.
            Type '() => number' is not assignable to type '() => string'.
              Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
                Type '() => Dependencies[DepName]' is not assignable to type '() => string'.
                  Type 'Dependencies[DepName]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
                    Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
                      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIQA4RAE2w4CAZ2QG8AoZZOALmSLClAHNLkAjOkAVwFt3obBHXYB7UQBsIcEOQC+5cmACeWNJmx4QCZQAUoogG7A8UEgF4ybANroMAOTi8UoZAGsIy0THVZc+QiIAXToACgBKZHMAPl9NAOJbTEdnIPlFFTU7eO1lACUIZmAGKGUoqyokhycXEHdPbzj-bUCQiqpkDANjUzDImKatAkS7FIg0qgUFcgQJOCISAGFRcDhQaHau4EM4SGQoaRwViTKuoxNoIjpdOCgwYDgJAB5s5p19c9MiWMtSBSotjs9gc4EcQCd9oVioxlNdbvdHi8NG98lCSsofmRplQDkUGNAkdVnMgIAAPSC4EgeLw+V5DQLRUJsKggGp0UY1AA0zM63QuUHZyKGej5XyqYwmyEiFA6yDAAAtigA6M49S7WVmpcqq-k8hXK3HQ0oampBcqkXmfDb-ZBTIA)

**UPDATE 2024/1/11**

[Working Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIQA4RAE2w4CAZ2QG8AoZZOALmSLClAHNLkAjOkAVwFt3obBHXYB7UQBsIcEOQC+5cmACeWZAAUoogG7A8UADwAVAHzIAvMgAUASgtmjilWvRZc+ZZp17oRA66IzSwoqAG1XADk4XhRQZABrCGVRGDRMIgBdOi9dfX908MwomIyTeSdVFFdsPBAEZQAlCGZgBihlfIxAizI2Qoxi2JAEpJS0rqzeqioMLVzobLmfQwD+wdK2BQVyBAk4IhIAYVFwOFBoTu6Q5FngbThIZChpHBOJZRul-SJsuCgwYBwCSdGoeHLLPwBExBMgKGZMe6PZ5wV4gd5PZqtRjKX7-QHA6ruOqNTFtDpQmGkbZUdigHCdQbICAAD0guBIiWSqShVjYVBA0QgdEigoANHzPt59IspRdViKSmUqHZrlQwAALVoAOlmsqgRFCApKPV18ygEo12ueLTJhsFGR6pElZuQcNd8iAA)

Comment: This sort of assignment only works if TS sees it as a "distributive object type" as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), which is the recommended approach to deal with this sort of "correlated" type operation (such as described in [ms/TS#35801](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)) and get compiler-verified safety.  With your code example it looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrEk1w). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! this is exactly the case. I was able to fix the issue by making the Container take the Dependencies as a generic argument. see the "working playground" link in my question

Comment: I'm confused; are you answering your own question? If so, you should probably post an answer and not an edit to the question.  Or are you just communicating with me out-of-band via a question update?  I'm happy to write up an answer but I'm not sure what to make of this answer-code-as-update-to-question development.